# How do I get Twitter hashtag to display on this code using custom fields?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter

I can't figure this out for the life of me. In this plugin, I want to use custom hashtags with the Twitter button. I'm only pasting some of the code.

I got a custom field type called tweethashtag. I'd that that whatever is in that custom field, for it to pick up. It needs to go between data-hashtag=" ". Everything works but this.

```
 $arrButtonsCode[] = '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="'.$title.'" data-url="'.$permalink.'" data-hashtag="'echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "tweethashtag", true);'"  ' . ((!empty($this->settings['twitterusername'])) ? 'data-via="'.$this->settings['twitterusername'].'" ' : '') . 'rel="nofollow"></a>';
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's the new code that runs correctly but does not echo the custom field tweethashtagpost inside the tweet button. The post does have tweethashtagpost entered.

```
 $arrButtonsCode[] = '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="'.$title.'" data-url="'.$permalink.'" data-hashtag="'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID, "tweethashtagpost", true).'"  ' . ((!empty($this->settings['twitterusername'])) ? 'data-via="'.$this->settings['twitterusername'].'" ' : '') . 'rel="nofollow"></a>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following:

```
.'" data-hashtag="'echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "tweethashtag", true);'
```

You need to concatenate the string like so

```
.'" data-hashtag="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, "tweethashtag", true).'
                   ^                                              ^
```

Also, notice the `;` and `echo` is taken out

Comment: Thanks for that.
I've got the custom field filled in for that post but it still doesn't seem want to take the hashtag.

Comment: @MichaelTieso can you explain more of what you want and what it is doing?

Comment: Sure. So if the customfield "tweethashtag" is filled out for the post, it'll display inside data-hashtag.

Comment: @MichaelTieso You may have to update your question to show what your code is now outputting. Update to your new code and what it give and an example of what you expect to happen